# Condition operators don't give correct result

Tags: ruby

I am trying to develop a battleship game in console. I need input of coordinates that guess where the game is. I did it:

```
#array1 and array2 are not obvious boards of player1 and player2 respectly 
array1 = [ ['*', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],['1',0, 1, 1, 1, 0], ['2',1, 0, 0, 0, 0], ['3',1, 0, 1, 0, 0], ['4',0, 0, 1, 0, 1], ['5',0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ]
array2 = [ ['*', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],['1',1, 0, 1, 1, 0], ['2',0, 0, 0, 0, 1], ['3',0, 1, 0, 0, 1], ['4',0, 1, 0, 0, 1], ['5',0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ]

#arr1 and arr2 are obvious boards of player1 and player2 respectly
arr1 = [['*', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],['1','.','.','.','.','.'],['2','.','.','.','.','.'],['3','.','.','.','.','.'],['4','.','.','.','.','.'],['5','.','.','.','.','.']]
arr2 = [['*', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],['1', '.','.','.','.','.'],['2', '.','.','.','.','.'],['3', '.','.','.','.','.'],['4', '.','.','.','.','.'],['5', '.','.','.','.','.']]
coor = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

#board1 and board2 are the final boards of player1 and player2
#this arrays will be seen during game 
#every changes will be seen on these boards
board1 = arr1.map { |x| x.join(' ') }
board2 = arr2.map { |x| x.join(' ') }

#num1 and num2 are the numbers of the parts of ships respectively
num1 = 8
num2 = 8

#count1 and count2 are the numbers of poped ship parts respectively
count1 = 0
count2 = 0

#Starting of the game and the printing the board 
#If we type "start" game will be started
#"Reset" game will be ended
#If we type words except "start" or "reset" program will ask "Do you want to start? (start/reset)" again
while true do
    puts "Welcome to the game!!!"
    puts "Do you want to start? (start/reset):"
    respond = gets.chomp
    if respond == 'start'
        puts "\n"
        puts "Player ONE"
        puts board1
        puts "\n"
        puts "Player TWO"
        puts board2

        while true do
            #Burada while ile player1 in shertleri olacaq 
            while true do 
                puts "\n"
                puts "Turn - Player ONE"
                puts "Enter coordinate: " 
                a = gets.chomp
                a1 = a.split('')
                b = coor.index(a1[0]) +1
                col1 = b
                row1= a1[1].to_i
                if a == '""'
                    puts "You have to enter any coordinate"
                    break
                elsif array1[row1][col1] == 'X' or array1[row1][col1] == '0'
                    puts "You have already bumped this coordinate!"
                elsif col1<1 or col1>5 or row1>5 or row1<1
                    puts "This coordinate is out of board"
                else
                    if array1[row1][col1] == 1
                        count1 = count1 + 1
                        arr1[row1][col1] = "X"
                    elsif array1[row1][col1] == 0
                        arr1[row1][col1] = "0"
                    end
                    board1 = arr1.map { |x| x.join(' ') }        
                    puts "\n"
                    puts "Player ONE"
                    puts board1
                    puts "\n"
                    puts "Player TWO"
                    puts board2

                    if count1 == num1
                        puts "Player ONE won the game!"
                        break
                    end
                end
                break
            end


            while true do 
                #Burada while ile player2 in shertleri olacaq 
                puts "\n"
                puts "Turn - Player TWO"
                puts "Enter coordinate: " 
                c = gets.chomp
                c1 = c.split('')
                d = coor.index(c1[0]) + 1
                col2 = d
                row2= c1[1].to_i
                if c == '""'
                    puts "You have to enter any coordinate"
                    break
                elsif array2[row2][col2] == 'X' or array2[row2][col2] == '0'
                    puts "You have already bumped this coordinate!"
                elsif col2<1 or col2>5 or row2>5 or row2<1
                    puts "This coordinate is out of board"
                else
                    if array2[row2][col2] == 1
                        count2 = count2 + 1
                        arr2[row2][col2] = "X"
                    elsif array2[row2][col2] == 0
                        arr2[row2][col2] = "0"
                    end
                    board2 = arr2.map { |x| x.join(' ') } 
                    puts "Player ONE"
                    puts board1
                    puts "\n"
                    puts "Player TWO"
                    puts board2

                    if count2 == num2
                        puts "Player TWO won the game!"
                        break
                    end
                end
                break
            end
        end

    elsif respond == 'reset'
        puts "You are off the game"
        break
    else
        puts "\n"
        puts "Answer can be only {start} or {reset}"
    end
end
```

There are some problems, and I added `if elsif else` conditions to the code to solve them. One of them is for entering coordinates out of board, the second one is for not entering any coordinate, and the last one is for bumped coordinate. If these three condition are bypassed, the players can enter any coordinate.

But these codes don't work. When I check these three conditions, the result is an error. Can anyone tell me what the problem is with these conditions? Why don't they give suitable result?

Comment: If this is a pure-Ruby question you should not have Rails tags. Nor do I see why there is a `rubygems` tag. Keep in mind how tags are used. Having a Rails tag may disappoint readers who filter their questions to Rails questions only and cause some readers who filter-out Rails questions to not see your question. Most pure-Ruby questions have just one tag: `Ruby`.

Comment: As I wrote I am very very very beginner in ruby. It is not even one week. That's why I dont understand difference between them. Therefore I wrote these tags.

Comment: I removed the superfluous tags for you. I recommend not adding tags whose definition you don’t know.

Comment: @anothermh Thank you so much. Do you have any idea about my question?

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting? I ran your code locally, and it seemed to work without giving me any errors.

Comment: When I enter for example A8 or do not enter coordinate  I get error. and when I enter the same coordinate again and again nothing happen

Comment: "stupid errors" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Also, please make sure to provide a [mcve], i.e. an example that only contains the *absolute* minimum amount of code to demonstrate your *specific* problem. Most problems, especially beginner problems require at most 3-5 lines of code to demonstrate. I am almost certain that your problem can be demonstrated in less than your 105 lines.

Answer (score 0):

When entering A8 as a value, the error you get is:

```
battleship.rb:54:in `<main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

This is line 54:

```
elsif array1[row1][col1] == 'X' or array1[row1][col1] == '0'
```

In this case, the error is that array1["8"] is nil, and nil["A"] is undefined. An easy fix is to move line 56 above this one (the one that checks whether the input is actually within the board range).

```
elsif col1<1 or col1>5 or row1>5 or row1<1
```

If you do that, then since 8 is greater than 5, you'll get the "out of board" message rather than an error.

---

The other error you mention is when you put in an empty string. In that case the error is:

```
battleship.rb:48:in `<main>': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Line 48 says:

```
b = coor.index(a1[0]) +1
```

In this case, the index is returning nil, and you can't add 1 to nil.

One way to fix this is to move the section a few lines down that checks whether a is blank to before line 48.

Comment: Okay. But how can I fix the the error in the line 48?